# DLL Entry Point of Windows Hook

Tags: winapi, dll, hook

I implement a DLL to record user's input by using SetWindowsHookEx function. 
Besides, I inject my DLL after the hooked program runs. 
The return values of SetWindowsHookEx indicate that they all hook the process successfully. 
However, I don't know why when I set my hook in DLL_THREAD_ATTACH , the message hook works good. But the hook will be disconnected when the thread dies, which is very annoying for me to log user's input. 
When I set my hook in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, it will enters that case, but it seems that my hook never receives the callback of HOOKPROC. 
 
Therefore, I only post DllMain and SetMyHook function. 
My code structure :

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch( ul_reason_for_call )
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            MainHwnd = GetMainWindow();
            SetMyHook(hWnd_tid, hInst);
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            ClearMyHook();
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI SetMyHook(DWORD tid, HMODULE hInstance)
{
    Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)MsgHook, hInstance, tid);
    MHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)MenuHook, hInstance, tid);
    if(Hook && MHook)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL ClearMyHook(void)
{
    if (UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook) && UnhookWindowsHookEx(MHook))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Notice: 
If I move the code in the case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH to DLL_THREAD_ATTACH, it will work!! 
I don't know why it will happen...

Comment: Only one thread in the process will get DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, maybe you end up hooking the wrong thread.

Comment: I've tested that when I set my hook in both DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH  and DLL_THREAD_ATTACH. After DLL injection,  it hooked one of the thread of that process , and there is no any callback from hookproc. but when the new thread is created, my dll will attach to the new thread, and it will receive callback from hookproc , why?

Comment: In general, you can't safely call GUI-related functions from DllMain.  Have you found any documentation to say that this is one of the exceptions?  One thing you could try is launching a new thread and setting the hooks from there; that would also allow you to control the thread's lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for Harry Johnston!!! Finally, I put CreateThread  in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH to slove this problem , and use a while loop in this threadproc to maintain lifetime.